# Mouse wheel scrolling is jumpy only on some boot ups

Tags: windows, drivers, mouse, scrolling

Sometimes I boot a windows 10, the mouse wheel is scrolling stably, not a single jump, but in some boots of windows it's all jumpy that I can't even scroll and have to use another method. It doesn't switch from jumpy to non-jumpy during the run of the windows, only when booted, if it's jumpy it will stay jumpy until reboot and vice versa.

Dell KM636

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse?

Comment: No, I don't have any.